# print exit code in cmd in windows os

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

print exit code in cmd in windows os ....some command return exit code ...where this code store...and i want to print this exit code and assign it to variable

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use %ERRORLEVEL% environment variable, it will hold the last code that was returned. You can echo it or assign it to a variable, depending on your needs.