# mochawesome cypress failure report

Tags: testing, mocha.js, cypress

I am using cypress and mochawesome to generate reports for testing. I  want to be alerted only when there is a failure. Is it possible to have the number of failing tests without parsing the json file?

Comment: can you share the code you have? what are the errors?

Comment: I don't have errors.I have  .json and .html reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exit code of the cypress process will give you the number of failed tests:

```sh
npm run cypress
# ... cypress runs...
echo $? # print number of failed tests
```

Or for Windows cmd prompt: [print exit code in cmd in windows os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819513/print-exit-code-in-cmd-in-windows-os#3819555)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I use CMD not linux terminal and I try to get the number of failed tests to try to send an email only if there is a failure